# No option to edit profile via the mobile app

Tags: support, profile-page, mobile-app

Why does Stack Exchange not allow me to change my profile details through mobile app?

Recently I wanted to edit my profile picture through the mobile app but there is no option to edit the profile or any information.

Can someone please tell me if I am missing something - is there any way to edit my profile in the mobile app?

Comment: @Chenmunka that's a feature request; this is a support request.